# Error: Cannot find control with path: 'specs -> 2' FormArray checkbox list

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formarray-checkbox?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

I am using reactive forms and in my forms I have an array of string with which I bind my checkbox list.

When I a trying to mark the returned array items to be selected, In console I am able to see the error

[image: Error message in console]

.ts code as follow :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  spec = ['site-1', 'site-2', 'site-4'];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      specs: this.fb.array(['site-1', 'site-2'].map(s => this.fb.control(true)))
    });
  }
}
```

and html code as follow :

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <b>Select Spec Rows</b>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group overflow" formArrayName="specs">
      <div *ngFor="let site of spec; let i = index">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          [id]="i"
          [formControlName]="i"
          [value]="site"
          (change)="specRowCheck($event,option.id, false)"
        />
        <div [innerHTML]="site"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**`ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'specs -> 2'`**

I checked other questions and its seems I am missing some form group in my html but I am not sure how to apply that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting formControlName directive for missing formControl that's why you getting this error.Since you using spec array in ngFor it have 3 value, in class you have only two array of formControl.

You should have 3 formControl inorder to match with spec array.

**Try this:**

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      specs: this.fb.array(this.spec.map(s => this.fb.control(true)))
 });
```

[Forked Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formarray-checkbox-kh8wcm?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: But in that case all three will be selected , I want only two be selected as my another service call returns only two of out of three. It’s case like of edit form and set checkbox checked which are earlier checked.

Comment: Based on another service you can set formControl value

Comment: Can you please include an example in your StackBlizt

Comment: I have update the stackblitz check the stackblitz now

Comment: What if I want to show every checkbox initially unselected and then later based on values in anotherServiceValue mark them as checked on button click. typical edit case .

Comment: You can use setValue or patchValue method on formArray check this:https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#replacing-a-form-control-value

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formarray-checkbox-u1b23f?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formarray-checkbox-kh8wcm?file=app/app.component.html try something like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234267/discussion-between-rahularyansharma-and-chellappan-).

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formarray-checkbox-zlv2tq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts